# What is a Union Word™?

Tags: knowledge, pattern, word-property

<sub>This is in the spirit of the [What is a Word/Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22what+is+a%22+word+is%3Aquestion) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463) with a special brand of [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Phrase%22%20user%3A463%20is%3Aquestion) and [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22What+is+%22+%22Word%22+-missing+user%3A463+is%3Aquestion) puzzles.</sub>

---

***After a long period of division, tends to unite; After a long period of union, tends to divide. This has been so since antiquity. - The Three Kingdoms***

If a word conforms to a special rule, I call it an Union Word™.
Use the following examples below to find the rule.

| Union Words™ | Not Union Words™ |
| --- | --- |
| ARGUMENT | PARAMETER |
| DEUCE | DRAW |
| PANASONIC | HITACHI |
| CANESUGAR | HONEY |
| FRAGMENT | SCRAP |
| NORTH | SOUTH |
| BRANCH | DIVISION |
| INDEX | EXPONENT |
| BELLY | BACK |
| SAUCEPAN | WOK |

And, if you want to analyze, here is a CSV version:

```
Union Words™,Not Union Words™
ARGUMENT,PARAMETER
DEUCE,DRAW
PANASONIC,HITACHI
CANESUGAR,HONEY
FRAGMENT,SCRAP
NORTH,SOUTH
BRANCH,DIVISION
INDEX,EXPONENT
BELLY,BACK
SAUCEPAN,WOK
```

**Hint 1:**

> Nation

Comment: One that can only be used exclusively with other Union words, else it will go on strike?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A Union Word is a

> Word whose first three letters are a valid [Alpha-3 country code](https://www.iban.com/country-codes).

ARGUMENT

> ARG -> Argentina

DEUCE

> DEU -> Germany

PANASONIC

> PAN -> Panama

CANESUGAR

> CAN -> Canada

FRAGMENT

> FRA -> France

NORTH

> NOR -> Norway

BRANCH

> BRA -> Brazil

INDEX

> IND -> India

BELLY

> BEL -> Belgium

SAUCEPAN

> SAU -> Saudi Arabia

Comment: Are you serious? Not again! :P

Comment: Not only country code but also those example are all in the UNIted natiON :P

Answer (score 7):

Here's my guess:

> A Union Word™ is a word which has its first three letters align with the three-letter abbreviation of a country name.

Evidence:

> Argument --> Argentina, Deuce --> Germany, Panasonic --> Panama, Canesugar --> Canada, Fragment --> France, North --> Norway, Branch --> Brazil, Index --> India, Belly --> Belize, Saucepan --> Saudi Arabia

Comment: Great answer, but I think you've been barely ninjaed! Great minds think alike...

Comment: Belize was the one that initially tripped me up too -- but Belize is actually BLZ!

Comment: I forgot all about that nation! (I was thinking of soccer and the World Cup as I was answering the puzzle.)

Comment: But FIFA have their own, slightly different system. I like the close misses in the counterexamples: parameter and honey.

Comment: Parameter annoyed me because I thought it was just first three letters at first, but the first non-Union word was a counterexample! I didn’t actually realize the official ones were PRY and HND for those two, respectively.

Comment: Would you like a bounty reward for your efforts since you have the correct answer, but have been ninja'd? ;)

Comment: @Cloudy7 still a nice work :P

Comment: @MrPie No, please don't bother. I can always solve other problems ;)